# How to disable a shortcut used by a website with a userscript (SquareSpace ESC)?

Tags: javascript, redirect, keyboard-shortcuts, userscripts

Some websites made with SquareSpace (for example this [website](https://pronuncian.com/podcast-archives)) redirect the user to the login page when <kbd>ESC</kbd> is pressed. How can I prevent this redirection?  (I am not the owner of this website so I can't disable this feature in the [Website Settings](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815858-Escape-key-login))

This is what I tried but this doesn't prevent the redirection from happening:

```
 if (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML.includes("squarespace") ==true){
        window.addEventListener("keydown", dispatchkeyboardSquareSpace);
       function dispatchkeyboardSquareSpace(key) {
       if (key.key == "Escape") { ///66 = b   https://keycode.info/
           console.log("escape neutralized because squarespace")
           };
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (it should be self explanatory):

```
Static.SQUARESPACE_CONTEXT.websiteSettings.useEscapeKeyToLogin = false;
```